# How to test a JSON array from Spray GET response?

Tags: json, scalatest, spray

Spray says that any normal data types, including `Seq` will get (un)marhsalled to/from JSON, automatically. For some reason, I don't experience this.

```
import spray.json._
import DefaultJsonProtocol._
...

class RestAPITest
  extends FlatSpec
  with Matchers
  with ScalatestRouteTest
  with MyRoute
{
  ...

  behavior of "MyRoute"

  it should "return a list as JSON" in {
    Get("/computers") ~> myRoute ~> check {
      status should equal(OK)

      // 'sbt test' gives:
      // "could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type spray.httpx.unmarshalling.FromResponseUnmarshaller[Seq[String]]"
      //
      responseAs[Seq[String]] should contain theSameElementsAs( List( "A01", "A02", "A03", "E01", "G04" ) )
    }
  }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try adding `import spray.httpx.SprayJsonSupport._`.

Comment: Seems to work, thanks! (some more problems I'll see tomorrow in detail)

Comment: This and upgrading to Spray 1.3.0 helped. The 'responseAs' line in wonderful in its simplicity! Go spray-json and scala! :) If you make the comment an answer I'll gladly approve it.

Comment: It would be a good idea to post your "Addendum" as the answer to your own question, as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Ended up mixing in the `spray.httpx.SprayJsonSupport` trait to my test class, to make explicit what is going on. This piece is simply a jewel - makes testing JSON REST API's essentially one-liners! Happy.

http://spray.io/documentation/1.1-SNAPSHOT/spray-httpx/spray-json-support/

Thanks @jrudolph :)